# Не видно капчу при регистрации

Tags: php

Добавил капчу(ввод цифр с картинки), при регистрации пользователей, но картинка черная, и цифр невидно. В чем может быть проблема? 
Файл captcha.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Генерируем случайное число.
    $rand = mt_rand(1000, 9999);

    // Сохраняем значение переменной  $rand ( капчи ) в сессию
    $_SESSION["rand"] = $rand;

    //создаём новое черно-белое изображение
    $im = imageCreateTrueColor(90,50);

    // Указываем белый цвет для текста
    $c = imageColorAllocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

    // Записываем полученное случайное число на изображение
    imageTtfText($im, 20, -10, 10, 30, $c, "fonts/verdana.ttf", $rand);

    header("Content-type: image/png");

    // Выводим изображение
    imagePng($im);

    //Освобождаем ресурсы
    imageDestroy($im);


?>
```

Фрагмент с капчей на форме:

```
<tr>
                            <td> Введите капчу: </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    <img src="captcha.php" alt="Капча" /> <br />
                                    <input type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="Проверочный код" required="required" />
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так будет работать, проверил

```
<?php
session_start();
$rand = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
$_SESSION["rand"] = $rand;

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(90, 50);

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 90, 50, $white); //заполняем белым фоном

imagettftext($im, 20, -10, 10, 30, $black, 'verdana.ttf', $rand); //убедитесь, что шрифт на месте

header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```